# make placeholder text reappear when no text is in the input field

Tags: javascript

I have an input text field with a placeholder attribute. The placeholder disappears when I enter text, but I would like the the placeholder text to reappear after I click the button, "clear," or when the text field is empty. What are some ways I can achieve this?

Below is the code I have below. I tried

```
document.text.value = "hello";
```

but the text "hello" stays in the box when I start typing.

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="hello">
<input type="button" value="clear" onclick(clearText)>
```

Javascript

```
function(clearText) {
 document.text.value = " ";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the text field is empty, the placeholder will reappear automatically.

When the clear button is clicked, you can use `onclick` attribute on the button and define the function like this:

Implementation with pure JS:

```
<script>
    function clearText() {
        // we use getElementById method to select the text input and than change its value to an empty string 
        document.getElementById("my_text").value = "";
    }        
</script>

<!-- we add an id to the text input so we can select it from clearText method -->
<input id="my_text" type="text" placeholder="hello">
<!-- we use onclick attribute to call the clearText method -->
<input type="button" value="clear" onclick="clearText();">
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/2yaoLbgt/3/)

---

Or you can use jQuery:

```
<script>
    function clearText() {
         $("#my_text").val("");
    }        
</script>

<input id="my_text" type="text" placeholder="hello">
<input type="button" value="clear" onclick="clearText();">
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/2yaoLbgt/2/)

Comment: Thanks. I like the simplicity of it and this was somewhat close to mine. Question, why do you have to select an id? Why doesn't it work if you just use the DOM until you get to that element?

Comment: You can use the DOM until you get to that element but you would need to dive into all the elements on the DOM until you get to that exact child node. Something like document.documentElement.children and so on..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it:

```html
<input placeholder="hello" onchange="if (this.value == '') {this.placeholder = 'hello';}"
/>
```

Comment: This is another way to look at it. But I would put the javascript in a script instead of the HTML.

Comment: yes but you should see that changing the placeholder or changing the input value (as you did) are different things,

this JS can go into script tag as well I've just showed you the way how to manage the problem

Answer (score 1):

You were very close

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id='theText' placeholder="hello">
<input type="button" value="clear" onclick='clearText()'>
```

JavaScript :

```
clearText = function(){
 document.getElementById('theText').value = "";
}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/7z957rh2/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your javascript syntax, starting from function declarations and ending with onclick event specification.
However, you were on the right way, and code below does the trick:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="hello">
<input type="button" value="clear" onclick="document.querySelector('input').value=''">
```

However, it will only work if this is the only input box in your document. To make it work with more than one input, you should assign it an id:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="hello">
<input type="button" value="clear" onclick="document.querySelector('#text1').value=''">
```

and use "text2" and so on for other fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should not forget to set "return false;"

```
document.getElementById('chatinput').onkeypress = function(){
var key = window.event.keyCode;

            if (key === 13) {

                    var text        = this.value;
                    var object      = document.getElementById('username_interface'); 
                    email           = object.email;
                    username        = object.username;
                    empty           = /^\s+$/;
```

// function Send Message

```
                    this.value      = "";

                    return false;

            }else{
                    return true;
}}
```